# Unable to add include path in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, boost, qt-creator

I've downloaded a C++ project which uses Boost. It's rather complicated and plenty of files reference its parts, like:

```
#include <boost/graph/fruchterman_reingold.hpp>
```

I've put Boost directory in the project folder and added `INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Programming/my-project"` in the `.pro` file but for some reason Qt keeps telling me "No such file or directory" about every single file. Now note that if I change the paths to absolute the references start working. I've ran Qmake explicitly but still get the same problem. What can I do about it besides changing all paths to absolute?

I'm running Qt Creator 3.3.0, Qt 5.4.0, the compiler is MinGW 4.9.1.

Comment: Let's do a test. Can you move the boost folder to root (C:\), change the INCLUDEPATH accordingly in the .pro file, and try again?

Comment: did you run qmake after changing the pro file? and rebuild the application?

Comment: @CapEnt Just tried that, still nothing

Comment: @user1767754 I do that after editing the .pro file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured it out. Apparently the project had several projects inside but I wasn't aware that I had to change `.pro` files in every single one to tell the compiler to add a new path. After I did it the problem was solved. Thank you for your time, people.